# Unable to Listen Incoming transaction on bitcoin Node using zeromq

Tags: zeromq

I have done setup and its config setup of bitcoin. I am trying to listen incoming transactions using zeromq I first tried to listen transaction using latest version but not work. Then tried with 5.3.1, 5.3.0 but that also not worked.

Here is my script...

```
var zmq = require("zeromq"),
sock = zmq.socket("sub");
sock.connect("tcp://52.66.249.25:29000");
sock.subscribe('hashtx');
console.log("Subscriber connected to port 29000");
sock.on("message", function (topic, message) {
console.log(topic.toString(), message.toString('hex'));
});
```

In above script RPC Host : "52.66.249.25" but that not worked. So then I change host in config and make changes in script and set host : 127.0.0.1 but from this port also i unable to listen an incoming transactions.

Here is my config file.

```
testnet=1
[test]
txindex=1
listen=1
server=1
rest=1
rpcbind=0.0.0.0
zmqpubrawblock=tcp://52.66.249.25:29000
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://52.66.249.25:29000
zmqpubhashtx=tcp://52.66.249.25:29000
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://52.66.249.25:29000
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=" "
rpcpassword=" "
rpcport=18332
```